# How to define an enum constant using the underlying value

Tags: f#, enums, constants

What is the F# equivalent of this C#:

```cs
const MyEnum None = (MyEnum)1;
```

This does not work:

```ml
[<Literal>]
let None : MyEnum = enum 1 //ERROR: not a valid constant expression
```

although, curiously, it's okay in an attribute constructor:

```ml
[<MyAttribute(enum 1)>]
type T = class end
```

The discrepancy seems odd.

#### UPDATE

This is fixed in v3.1 and works as expected.

Comment: Yes, it is quite odd and I would not be surprised if it was fixed in some future release of F# \*cough\*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the observed compiler behavior is intentional and completely in line with restrictions for values having `[<Literal>]` attribute defined by [F# Language Spec $10.2.2:](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html)

> The right-hand side expression must be a **literal** constant expression that is made up of either:
>
> - A simple constant expression, with the exception of (), native integer literals, unsigned native integer 
>     literals, byte array literals, BigInteger literals , and user-defined numeric literals.
>     —OR—
> - A reference to another literal

Consider

```
type MyEnum =
| Case1 = 1
| Case2 = 2
```

then

```
[<Literal>]
let Valid: MyEnum = MyEnum.Case1 // Literal enumeration case on the right
```

will happily compile, but

```
[<Literal>]
let Invalid: MyEnum = enum<MyEnum>(1) // Expression on the right
                                      // generating constant value, which
                                      // potentially might be completely off
                                      // legit MyEnum cases
```

will not, although outside of `[<Literal>]` context both statements will compile into absolutely identical IL.

Assuming that `[<Literal>]` attribute is the only F# way of making C# `const` equivalent the only option for defining enumeration literal value would be using a literal enumeration case of proper type on the right side of `let`.

Comment: It being valid in an attribute constructor is what I find confusing. I would expect similar rules for attribute arguments and literals. The F# spec is silent on the matter, but the C# spec [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664616(v=vs.71).aspx) that an attribute argument (`E`) must be: a constant, a System.Type object, or a one-dimensional array of `E`...and yet, the `enum` function works in that context.

Comment: In short, `enum 1` is treated as a constant (?) in an attribute constructor, but not when defining a literal. Bug?

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting, `enum` merely forwards to `unboxPrim` (via `EnumOfValue`) which is defined: `let inline unboxPrim<'T>(x:obj) = (# "unbox.any !0" type ('T) x : 'T #)` ...a magic function for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy is caused by the fact that C# `(MyEnum)0` *is* indeed a literal, but F# `enum` is a function of type `int32 -> 'T`.
I believe it would not be difficult for F# team to add special processing for this construct, but unfortunately it is not there yet.

Nevertheless, there is one way to accomplish what you need, but only for `0` value:

```
type MyEnum =
    | None = 0
    | Foo = 1

[<Literal>]
let X = MyEnum()
```

Comment: Interesting. I picked `0` arbitrarily for my example. It makes little sense that `enum` can be used within an attribute, but not a constant.

Comment: @Daniel Do you have an example where you need numeric value for a `Literal`, but can't use an enum value?

Comment: Here's [the example (on fpish)](http://fpish.net/topic/Some/0/76115) that inspired the question.